# How do I get this div to fill the entire horizontal width of the document, not the browser window?

Tags: html, css, width, scrollbar

I've got the following HTML and CSS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body, div, html {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      body {
        background: #727272;
      }

      #div1 {
        background: #F00;
        height: 50px;
      }

      #div2 {
        background: #F0F;
        height: 50px;
        width: 1500px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="div1">
    </div>
    <div id="div2">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

If I shrink the browser window down to less than 1500px (the width of `div2`), and then use the browser's horizontal scrollbar to scroll to the right, the width of `div1` remains cut off at the width of the browser window, and does not stretch all the way across the screen like `div2`.

Is there any way to get `div1` to always stretch across the screen, regardless of the width of `div2`?
Please note that in my real code, the width of `div2` is always changing, so I cannot just set a fixed width for `div1` via CSS.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
  #div1 {
    background: #F00;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your css try

display: block;

Comment: The divs are already `display: block` by default. This doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

put a wrapper around these two divs...

```
<div id="div0">
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <div id="div2"></div>
</div>
```

Then style the wrapper and divs accordingly

```
#div0 { display:table; }
#div1 {
    display:block;    
    width: 100%;
    background: #F00;
    height: 50px; }
#div2 {
    display: block;    
    background: #F0F;
    height: 50px;
    width: 1500px; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ls7aj/

Comment: The Fiddle is fine, but when I actually try to incorporate this into my code, it doesn't work.

Comment: without your code, who knows what your framework may be doing to prohibit the behavior...make something more detailed in jsfiddle if you continue to have issues

Answer (score 0):

Using `overflow:hidden` on the body, html, #container will do the trick.

Add a `width:100%;` to #div1 and you're good to go.

http://jsfiddle.net/tCN8H/

Edit: Changed `#Content` to `#container`

Comment: There is no `#content` div, and `overflow: hidden` just cuts off the page, making it completely unscrollable.

Comment: Ah, I just read that you wanted it to maintain a 100% width constantly, which the above code does. 

From my experience however, unless you're building a horizontal website, you shouldn't be having horizontal scroll bars. Poor user experience: http://www.experiencesolutions.co.uk/blog/2011/12/12/a-ux-perspective-on-horizontal-scrolling/

Comment: I agree that the UX is bad, but just imagine that `div2` is actually a massive table with lots of columns, and it has been dictated to me from above that I have to let it go off the screen if the content area is too small. Now what? Also, there is no `#container` div either.

Comment: Good point. However there are a few ways of doing the 'massive table'. I would personally go for a scroll bar within the table, the table being 100% width of the page (with a padding around the body), and add something like:    `.tableName{overflow: auto;width: 100%;}`
Anyway this is going slightly, off topic. Just something to think about Hartley. Good luck with your project! :-)

Comment: Thanks. That's a good idea. You are right though in that at the end of the day, there is absolutely no way to make a massive table look good. I keep insisting that a large table is a sign of poor design and not truly meeting the users' needs, but nevertheless, I have no choice in the matter and have to make it work. I'm thinking what I will ultimately do is add a checkbox that allows the user to choose whether to have a big table at its full width (that shoots off the screen), or to condense it down to 100% the width of the content, thus making the columns super narrow.

Comment: That's not a bad idea, giving a user more freedom with the data they see is good. 
I've just found this (as I was curious myself how best to display large tables.)
http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1459/how-to-display-too-much-data
It seems that formatting numeric values is a good start.
Personally I prefer drilling down into the data. 
Or tab controls for different groups of data. (I work for an MIS department in a college so these are the problems I have to deal with.) I know your pain!

Comment: Yeah, I saw that exact page before, and it was helpful. I also like drilling down into the data, but part of the problem is that my users' needs are so varied, it's hard to give them all what they want, so we often produce a huge data set, and them let them export to Excel and do what they want.